# Webpack dev server HMR not working with TypeScript modules

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I have a Vue 2 application that is mostly JS, and I am trying to introduce some new TypeScript modules and components.

When I start the webpack dev server, the application loads and works fine. However, when I make a change and the page automatically reloads, it gives an error:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR

D:\Code\app\js_src\core\ui\alert.ts
./js_src/core/ui/alert.ts 19:19-72
[tsl] ERROR in D:\Code\app\js_src\core\ui\alert.ts(19,20)
      TS2307: Cannot find module './alert.ts?vue&type=custom&index=0&blockType=Action' or its corresponding type declarations.


ERROR

D:\Code\app\js_src\components\AlertRenderer.vue.ts
[tsl] ERROR in D:\Code\app\js_src\components\AlertRenderer.vue.ts(34,25)
      TS2307: Cannot find module '@/components/reusable/overlays/ModalWindow.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.


ERROR

D:\Code\app\js_src\components\AlertRenderer.vue.ts
[tsl] ERROR in D:\Code\app\js_src\components\AlertRenderer.vue.ts(35,21)
      TS2307: Cannot find module '@/components/reusable/helpers/SvgIcon.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.


ERROR

D:\Code\app\js_src\components\AlertRenderer.vue.ts
[tsl] ERROR in D:\Code\app\js_src\components\AlertRenderer.vue.ts(37,10)
      TS2614: Module '"@/core/ui/alert"' has no exported member 'Alerts'. Did you mean to use 'import Alerts from "@/core/ui/alert"' instead?


ERROR

D:\Code\app\js_src\components\AlertRenderer.vue.ts
[tsl] ERROR in D:\Code\app\js_src\components\AlertRenderer.vue.ts(37,18)
      TS2614: Module '"@/core/ui/alert"' has no exported member 'Alert'. Did you mean to use 'import Alert from "@/core/ui/alert"' instead?


ERROR

D:\Code\app\js_src\components\AlertRenderer.vue.ts
[tsl] ERROR in D:\Code\app\js_src\components\AlertRenderer.vue.ts(37,25)
      TS2614: Module '"@/core/ui/alert"' has no exported member 'Action'. Did you mean to use 'import Action from "@/core/ui/alert"' instead?
```

`webpack.dev.js`

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: '/static/dist/index.html'
        },
    },
});
```

`webpack.common.js`

```
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './js_src/index.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/dist/',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'js_src'),
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          esModule: false, // workaround for [object Module] bug
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
        }
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js_src/index.html.ejs'),
      favicon: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js_src/images/logo.png'),
    }),
  ],
};
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./static/dist",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./js_src/*"]
    },
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "preserve"
  }

}
```

It works fine if I compile it using the above config, or change the component script lang to JS.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out using `ts-loader` and `babel-loader` side by side produces some weird effects:

```
  {
    test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    options: {
      plugins: [
        ["@babel/transform-runtime", {
          "regenerator": true
        }]
      ],
      presets: [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        [
          '@babel/preset-typescript', // reference typescript plug-in
          {
            allExtensions: true, // supports all file extensions
          },
        ],
      ],
    },
  },
```

In my `webpack.common.js` fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

svbnet

I also had this issue, in my case, I solved it like this:

```
{
  loader: 'ts-loader',
  options: {
    transpileOnly: true, // by adding this, it helps you skip the typing check while compiling
    appendTsSuffixTo: [ /\.vue$/ ]
  }
}
```